# I was wondering if anyone could provide me with a method to solving as I do not know what I am doing wrong after multiple attempts?

Tags: stoichiometry, concentration

A portland cement sample contained 20% SiO2 by weight derived
from two silicate compounds, SiO2.2CaO and SiO2.3CaO that
are present in the cement in the mole ratio 3 : 4. Determine
the percent by weight of each silicate compound in the
cement.

Answer key from book  : 24.57%, 43.43%

My answer: 36.03%, 63.09%

Assuming the first silicate compound as W1 & the second one as W2 and their overall composition contribution to the sample as 100%. I got one equation W1+W2= 357.4 and using the mole ratios given, I equated them to get W1= .564 *W2. upon resubstituting that into the first equation, I got 128.8 g for W1 and 228.51 g for W2. Calculating the percentages for each, I got 36.03% and 63.9 % respectively. –

Note: I do find the percentages from the answer key weird too as they don't quite indicate a 100% composition contribution from the constituents. Or, maybe I am just missing something.

The help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should include you solution as well.l, not just your result.

Comment: Ok. Assuming the first silicate compound as W1 & the second one as W2 and their overall composition contribution to the sample as 100%. I got one equation   
W1+W2= 357.4  and using the mole ratios given, I equated them to get              
 W1= .564 *W2. upon resubstituting that into the first equation, I got 128.8 g for W1 and 228.51 g for W2. Calculating the percentages for each, I got 36.03% and 63.9 % respectively.

Comment: Technical note: The question improvement should be done in the question itself, not in the comments. Factual note: There is not said W1&W2 contribution is 100%. You also do not respect their ratio 3:4.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the main mistake. w1+w2 is not equal to the weight of cement.

Comment: You should give your question some *meaningful* title.

Comment: @Karl I honestly do not understand how your comment helps solve the problem. But sure, your concern has been duly noted.

Comment: SE is not just a forum, questions and answers should be written in a way so they can be found and used later by someone *else*, who gets stuck with a similar problem. Instead of trying to be ironic, you should rather do something about it.

Comment: Just to enforce the comment of M. Farooq. The exercise is fine there is no reason the two must add the 100.  And generally speaking one can as well ask for the percent content of, eg, Cao, in a batch of pure Ca(OH)2...

Answer (score -2):

This problem seems to have wrong data ! Look !
The molar mass of $Ca_2SiO_4$ is $172$. The molar mass of $Ca_3SiO_5$ is $228$. If you mix $3$ moles $Ca_2SiO_4$, (= $516$ g), and $4$ moles $Ca_3SiO_5$, (= $912$ g), the total weight is : $516 + 912  = 1428$ g. This mixture contains $3+4 = 7$ moles of $SiO_2$, which weighs $420$ g. In this mixture, the ratio $SiO_2$/total mass = $420/1428$ = $29.4$%. Well. This is contrary to the initial data saying that the proportion of $SiO_2$ is $20$% !!! Where is the mistake or the misconception ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Maurice. I have a link here that will direct you to site I retrieved  the question from. I just rechecked it and it has been presented as is.   
 Pg 72, problem 3.44 -                                      
          https://vdocuments.site/stoichiometry-and-process-calculations-1.html

Comment: No, I am afraid the above calculation is not correct. Why are you assuming the total weight of calcium silicates is the total weight of cement?